# Override related manager to add additional filter

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Category(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=55, unique=True)
    parent = ForeignKey('self', on_delete=CASCADE, null=True, related_name='subcategories', blank=True)
    visible = BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
```

How can I override the behavior of `c.subcategories`, so that only visible categories are fetched.

For example, `c=Category.objects.get(id=1)`.

`c.my_related_manager.all()` is equivalent to `c.subcategories.filter(visible=True)`

Comment: If you do this you may cause yourself issues when you want to get the non-visible subcategories (when you want to editi the category for example). What's wrong with using `filter`?

Comment: If I want to find visible subcategories for 20 categories, this will hit the database 20 times.  The workaround is to filter python-side.

Comment: You mean in a template?

Comment: Overriding the manager will not prevent the repeated queries, you should use `prefetch_related`. Can you add your code to your question?

Comment: Queries are not repeated if I do Category.objects.prefetch_related('subcategories'). They are repeated when I filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) to add a filter to a `prefetch_related` call

```
categories = Category.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('subcategories', queryset=Category.objects.filter(visible=True))
)
for category in categories:
    print(category.subcategories.all()) # Will print only visible categories
```